# Update Query with PDO becames delete

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a update query using PDO,
but when I execute it, it deletes my record.

```
public function update($e) {
    $sql = 'UPDATE experiences SET company = :company, position = :position, duty = :duty WHERE id = :id';
    //$this->operaction($sql, $e);
    $id = $e['id'];
    $company = $e['company'];
    $position = $e['position'];
    $duty = $e['duty'];

    $pdostmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $pdostmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $pdostmt->bindValue(':company', $company, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdostmt->bindValue(':position', $position, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdostmt->bindValue(':duty', $duty, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdostmt->execute();
}
```

$e is an array of $_POST array('id' => '6', 'company' => 'webcanada', 'position' => 'web developer', 'duty' => 'build website');
Can anyone suggest I have done wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: what is the content of `$e`? Can you post a `var_dump`?

Comment: When you say *deleted*, you mean that manually running `SELECT * FROM experiences WHERE id =` [the ID you're testing with] returns zero result rows after this function is called?  (And it returns one row before fn is called?)

Comment: An update query deleting a record would be the greatest bug in mysql ever, so it is extremely unlikely that your record gets deleted. I can imagine its fields being set to an empty string or null. This means that you have to check your input variables.

Comment: @tereško I have added the value of $e

Comment: I fixed it, it is all controller's issue, I forgot to put a break after the update method in the switch statement